# Push div next to centered and responsive Bootstrap container element

Tags: html, css, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3

There is a centered and responsive Bootstrap `container` with content in it. I want to push a div next to the container (right side, same `top` position as `container`) without affecting the centered container.

The problem is, when i add `float: left` to the container and `float: right` to the outer div, the container is not centered anymore. Only `float: right` to the outer div pushes the div only to the right side, but how to go on after?

I think `position: absolute` with fixed `width` is no option because the responsive `container` will change its `width` with different viewports.

Is there a chance to fix this only with HTML and CSS without JavaScript?

```css
.main-content {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.outer {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container main-content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      Here ist the content... Here is the content... Here is the content... Here ist the content... Here is the content... Here is the content... Here ist the content... Here is the content... Here is the content... Here ist the content... Here is the content...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      Here ist the content... Here is the content... Here is the content... Here ist the content... Here is the content... Here is the content... Here ist the content... Here is the content... Here is the content... Here ist the content... Here is the content...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outer">
  Outer
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you ok with it not being visible when the window is too small for the container?

If you just want it to be outside the container to the top right, you can use some relative/absolute positioning and move the "outer" div inside the main container.

```
.main-content {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position:relative;
}

.outer {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: yellow;
  position:absolute;
  right:-70px;
  top:0px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 70px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8ahrxtsk/4/

If you want it inside the container, just change the "right" position to 0px.

Comment: That's ok when the window is too small. Great, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Is this the behavior that you are looking for?

```css
.main-content {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container main-content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      Here ist the content... Here is the content... Here is the content... Here ist the content... Here is the content... Here is the content... Here ist the content... Here is the content... Here is the content... Here ist the content... Here is the content...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      Here ist the content... Here is the content... Here is the content... Here ist the content... Here is the content... Here is the content... Here ist the content... Here is the content... Here is the content... Here ist the content... Here is the content...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
      Outer
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or this:

```css
.main-content {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
.outer {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  top: 0;
  right: -100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container main-content">
  <div class="outer">
    Outer
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      Here ist the content... Here is the content... Here is the content... Here ist the content... Here is the content... Here is the content... Here ist the content... Here is the content... Here is the content... Here ist the content... Here is the content...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      Here ist the content... Here is the content... Here is the content... Here ist the content... Here is the content... Here is the content... Here ist the content... Here is the content... Here is the content... Here ist the content... Here is the content...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was looking for the second behavior. Also great solution but Sean was a little faster. Thank you too!