# Bootstrap 4: position <div> in a responsive way next to centered image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am creating an image gallery and I want to display the images in the following way:

[image]

So the image should always be centered and if there is enough space to the right, a `<div>` containing some information should be positioned to its right. Otherwise, the information box should be pushed below the image.

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40293292/push-div-next-to-centered-and-responsive-bootstrap-container-element) a similar question is asked, but in their case the information box will be positioned to the right of the image no matter what. This is their code: [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/8ahrxtsk/4/)

How can I achieve that it gets positioned below the image when the screen gets too narrow? I am using Bootstrap 4.

**Edit**
I tried Zims approach, but it doesn't really work with upright pictures:
[image: Screenshot]
I'd like to have the box with the metadata right next to the image...
Here the HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row align-items-md-end">

    <div class="px-1 col-xl-6 offset-xl-3 text-center">
        <div class="photoboxTest">
             <div class="text-center">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/ddofbxz8d/image/upload/v1543814237/nwzv41b8gddr1uf873ki.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="my-navigation d-flex justify-content-between">
                <a class="icon"><i class="fas fa-info-circle mx-2" style="color: transparent"></i></a>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <a class="icon" href="#"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
                    <a class="icon" href="/photos"><i class="fas fa-th mx-3"></i></a>
                    <a class="icon" href="#"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                </div>
                <a class="icon" href="#"><i class="fas fa-info-circle mx-2"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="px-1 col-xl-3">
        <div class="metabox ">
            <div class="my-title text-center">
                <h4>Metadata</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="my-metadata">
                <table style="width:100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Date</td>
                        <td>10.12.1992</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Time</td>
                        <td>12:14</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Location</td>
                        <td>This 1 nice location</td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Focal length</td>
                        <td>80 mm</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Aperture</td>
                        <td>f/10</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Exposuse time</td>
                        <td>10 s</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ISO</td>
                        <td>200</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the code that shows what you've attempted to so far.

Comment: I couldnt proberly try your solution because I was busy the last days, I will let you know how it went after I tried it and if it works I'll accept your post as solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

i can do without bootstrap. i suppose that's what you want.

```css
body {
  padding:10px;
}

.flex {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  align-items:flex-end;
  margin:0 auto;
  justify-content:center;
}


.picture {
  margin-right:10px;
  align-content:center;
 
}
  
.text {
  max-width:calc((100% - 300px)/2);
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}

.cont {
  position:relative;
}


@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .flex {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:flex-end;
}
  
  .picture {
    margin:0 auto;
  }
  
  .text {
    margin: 10px auto 0;  
    width:300px;
    top:310px;
    right:calc((100% - 300px)/2);
    transform:translateX(calc((100% - 300px)/2));
    max-width:300px;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="cont">
<div class="flex">
<div class="picture">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" alt="">
</div>
</div>
<div class="text">
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat veniam ipsum, placeat laboriosam dolor harum? Labore, sequi in. Modi aliquam, quae officiis quaerat mollitia magni incidunt nobis ipsa inventore autem.
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: but can the image be centered?

Comment: Thank you, but now both image and text are centered. I only want the image to be centered and the text should appear next to the centered image...

Comment: again look :) it must be now. you can give max-width to text.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is titled and tagged **Bootstrap 4**, here's the solution. There's no reason to use extra CSS.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center align-items-md-end text-center">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <img src="//placehold.it/400x480" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            Nullam sapien massa, aliquam in cursus ut, ullamcorper in tortor. 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/ZTLELR7tRk

Comment: but also in your solution the problem is that the image is not centered in the wide view...

Comment: Then just offset the grid columns, and use whatever col width you want for the image. I updated the demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/ZTLELR7tRk